# Verify Green's theorem for circle centered at $(x,y)=(a,0)$.

Tags: integration, vectors, circles, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Verify Green's theorem on the plane for the vector field $\ \mathbf F =3xy\mathbf i -x\mathbf j$ along the circle$\ c$ of radius$\ a$ centred at $\ (x,y)=(a,0)$ with counterclockwise direction.

Clearly the equation of the circle is

$\ y^2+(x-a)^2=a^2$,

rearranging and using polar coordinates yields

$\ 0\le r\le 2a\cos\theta$, and$\ -\frac \pi2\le \theta \le \frac \pi2$, correct?

Using Green's theorem I then arrive at

$\ \iint(-1-3x)dxdy$,

and using polar coordinates

$\ \int_{-\frac \pi2}^{\frac \pi2}\int_0^{2a\cos\theta}(-r-3ar\cos\theta) drd\theta$

Solving this integral I get$\ -4\pi a^2$.

I am struggling to solve the integral as a work integral (which I'll need to do in order to prove Green's theorem).

Could somebody please verify my answer using Green's theorem, and explain how I can set up a work integral in order to prove my answer via Green's theorem?

Thanks!

Edit: Please avoid using a parameterisation method for the solution; I have not been taught this and don't completely understand, sorry!

Comment: Why the angle only between $-\pi/2\,,\,\,\pi/2\; $ ? This only gives you the right semisphere of the circle...

Comment: The angle,$\ \theta$, is taken positively counterclockwise from the x-axis, and the circle is centred at$\ (a,0)$ not$\ (0,0)$, so$\ \theta$ cannot exceed the limits$\ -\frac \pi2 \le \theta \le \frac \pi2$.